# How to use SMS verification code by sending otp?

Tags: android, sms, one-time-password

```js
package com.surbhi.smsappacme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.digits.sdk.android.AuthCallback;
import com.digits.sdk.android.Digits;
import com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton;
import com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsException;
import com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TWITTER_KEY="LmrOrmpo6DuXmOG8EZxxa4tvpyJoJ";
    String TWITTER_SECRET="9P33l4tRaFwDR7FG05Nvffi9Z4JQ2zUiSnTXsgWGcK6c646Z9wZMu";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().build());
        Digits.Builder digitsBuilder = new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme);
//        Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), digitsBuilder.build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
        digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for "
                        + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
                Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```css
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.surbhi.smsappacme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.surbhi.smsappacme">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                android:value="LmrOrmpo6DuXmOG8EZtvpyJoJ"
                />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```css
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
                maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.surbhi.smsappacme.MainActivity">

    <com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton
        android:id="@+id/auth_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have four fields in my registration screen (username,email,password,mobile number) and I want to send a n `OTP` to the user for verification purpose. Is there any easy way to implement this by using a single `API`.

Comment: You need a server and an sms gateway for this

Comment: simple and best way is Firebase   refer this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: There is fabric Kit called Digits - https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/overview.html Maybe this is what you are  looking for?

Comment: You need to use SMS gateway for that and communicate with your server !

Comment: Using Firebase you can easily verify the gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cognalys (a free international mobile number verification library)
to see the integretion tutotial:just look here

https://cognalys.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000606584-integration-tutorial-

Comment: But i am not getting the OTP @Envy

Comment: What Sir..? @Piyush

Comment: @SurbhiSharma You can use Twillo for your requirement !! I am using the same !

Comment: @SurbhiSharma Solved??

Comment: I dont know how to get twitter key and twitter secret for that   @Piyush

Comment: @SurbhiSharma Its too easy you need to integrate in ur app

Answer (score 0):

you need to use any sms gateway for this. febric digits give you free smsapi for sending message to mobile. please check below link [Digits](https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits)

Comment: Sir i dont have twitter key and secret for that @Himesh Goswami